# YAP stop working after MikTex update

Tags: errors, miktex, windows

I spend some weeks searching for potential answers for a similar problem without success. This happened after one of many MikTex updates I made but it is unclear to me the source of the problem. My yap.exe file has the date of 29 Oct'16, so this might give you some useful clue. I usually compile my documents to pdf and so I only use dvi and yap to do tests and quick debugging. In one such ocasion while opening the dvi with yap an error window open with the message "MiKTeX encountered an internal error." The report info is the following

```
MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Data: 
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\mfmodes.cpp
Line: 50
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit, Service Pack 1, build 7601
Invokers: non-existing/explorer/TeXnicCenter
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Users\Myaccount\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
Root1: C:\Users\Myaccount\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
Root2: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
Root3: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
UserInstall: C:\Users\Myaccount\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserConfig: C:\Users\Myaccount\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9
UserData: C:\Users\Myaccount\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonInstall: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9
CommonConfig: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
CommonData: C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9
```

The problem is the same regardless if I compile a document within TeXnicCenter or just try to open a dvi file directly from a directory or even if I just double-click on yap.exe. I guess there is no problem in compiling to a dvi document, just opening it.

Many thanks for your support

Comment: Please make a bug report on the MiKTeX homepage ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to "MiKTeX settings (admin)". Click "Refresh FNDB" and "Update Formats". Now it should work.